# Search based on Second value in a map

Tags: algorithm, dictionary

I have a mapping of **String id -> Object**. Apart from merely having to insert and delete into this map, I would also need to find the id with the lowest x-value (x-value is a member in the Class from which the Object is instantiated).

Initially I thought I could just create another mapping  **x-value -> String id** for this. But that does not help this much, because in case of Remove operation, I have to now anyway search this second map for a particular id (so we are back to the main problem itself now).

Any suggestions to do this efficiently? (time wise - memory is not a big constraint)

EDIT: I think I could just get the x-value from the id (for removal function) and remove from second map using the x-value. Another thing here - the x-value is a float. Good idea to use float as a key in a map ?? Maybe using fabs and a precision value could do the trick here for floating point comparisons ?

EDIT #2: Unfortunately I remembered why the above method might not work (I was busy with other stuff and forgot about this project for a while). The x-value for different map entries NEED NOT BE UNIQUE. String ID is the primary key. So I need to use a multimap and use equal_range.

Comment: Why do you search for id when you can retrieve the x-value from the first map before deleting?

Comment: That sounds like it might work. Please see EDIT.

Comment: @Titan - If you're concerned about the floating point lookup performance perhaps you could generate a hash for each x-value and store with the object as another field, then use the hash as the key in the second map - of course if you can modify the class that instantiates the objects..

Comment: As long as you don't calculate these values but only copy and store them you can compare them for equality on bitlevel. If you need some sort of nearest match that would of course be harder and not on bitlevel anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution of using an auxiliary map isn't as bad as your post suggests.

It is true that a removal operation would require a lookup in the second map. However, this lookup can be done in `O(log n)` time. This is unlikely to be a deal breaker. If it is, please post more details.

Comment: Yes, on second thoughts it might just work. Have to run and see (but I think it will definitely work better than the linear single-map method I use for the min lookup - go through the entire map and return the iterator with the lowest x-value).

Answer (score 1):

How often do you remove objects? Usually in cases like that you have to think about the frequency of operations too. If the Removing is done infrequently than your solution with the second map could be quite good.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not so easy to estimate (because of the dynamic nature of the conditions for removal, addition and lookup). But for some really large inputs - I tend to notice that the lookup causes a big performance bottleneck.

Comment: @Titan, is that the lookup for the Remove operation that causes the bottleneck?

Comment: Oh sorry - to be clear I meant the lookup for the minimum x-value.

Comment: @Titan.. and you're observing that with the second map? or without? because what I was suggesting was to use the second map approach and to just take the hit on remove if the remove op is not as frequent as the other operations

Comment: Without second map.Yes I have to run with the second map and see what happens.  What I meant to say is that I am not sure if taking a hit on the REMOVE would actually be a bottleneck or not (because these operations are dynamically called). Guess its time to code !! Moreover on the basis of asymptotic run times - REMOVE is still O(log N).

Answer (score 1):

If you use tree map for the second mapping, you will immediatelly have minimum element and it will take O(log n) to remove element from it.

One other alternative is to use priority queue backed by double linked list to find minimal element and in first map remember direct reference to the node of the element. This node can be used for removal.

Comment: Tree map? - I think an STL implementation of a map is already a height balancing R-B tree. Your second solution seems good - but a little complex.

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate specific language. I tend to think in terms of Java and think of regular Map as a hash map. So first solution is not different from your own.